# Unable to locate network scripts package

Tags: locate

I’m trying to install network-scripts package on ubuntu and keep receiving the error “unable to locate package”. Is there a different name for network scripts?

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't have a `network-scripts` package.  The equivalent of the Red Hat  network-scripts is in `/etc/network/interfaces` file where you set pretty much the same as you would have in Red Hat, CentOS, etc.

Comment: What do you expect to get from this mythical `network-scripts` package? Do you want `network-tools`? Use `apt-cache search network` to see many packages. Perhaps, if you [edit] your Question to fully describe your end goal, we could help more.